# Firebase: Convert promise to async/await

Tags: javascript

Below is the code snippet which uses promise(**.then**) and it works fine but when i convert it to **async await** I get an error which is caught by the catch block

Promise -

```
exports.createScream = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "Method not allowed" });
  }
  const newScream = {
    body: req.body.body,
    userHandle: req.body.userHandle,
    createdAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
  };
  admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("screams")
    .add(newScream)
    .then(doc => {
      res.json({ message: `document ${doc.id} created successfully` });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({ error: "something went wrong" });
      console.error(err);
    });
});
```

Async/Await -

```
exports.createScream = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "Method not allowed" });
  }

  try {
    const newScream = {
      body: req.body.body,
      userHandle: req.body.userHandle,
      createdAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
    };
    const res = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("screams")
      .add(newScream);
    return res.json({
      message: `document ${doc.id} created successfully`
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: "something went wrong" });
  }
});
```

Please let me know whats wrong with Async/Await part of the code

Comment: `const res` change to any other value, bcoz in your endpoint params have `res`

Comment: const doc = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("screams")
      .add(newScream);

Comment: It seems krbalaji and user2222 already spotted the mistake in your code. In future questions please include the exact error message, and (if available) stack trace, you get as it'll make helping much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @user2222's comment above `const doc = await admin .firestore() .collection("screams") .add(newScream);` resolved the issue